# Visitors who visit at least once/week during a month?

Tags: google-analytics

Is there a way to get the number of unique visitors who visited at least once/week during a given month from Google Analytics?

If we had a SQL table to representing `visits` with at least the following fields:

```
+-------------+
| visits      |
+-------------+
| visitorId   |
| monthOfYear |
| weekOfYear  |
+-------------+
```

The SQL might look *something* like this:

```
select count(*) as 'regular visitors' from (
  select
    count(*) as 'visitor'

  from
    visits

  where
    monthOfYear = month(now())

  group by
    visitorId

  having
    count(distinct weekOfYear) >= 4
) bt
```

Can something similar be accomplished in Analytics?

**ADDENDUM**: We're tracking a user GUID in Custom Variable 1. If we can use that for grouping in some way, that would be ideal.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about analytics.

Comment: Analytics is on-topic on Webmasters, but I'm unsure of whether the processing portion would be okay there.

Comment: @jonsca OK. I wasn't sure which would be more fitting. Are you able to migrate the question?

Comment: I have a feeling they may close it over there because while you are simply trying to present your criteria in a logical fashion, it may look too much like a programming problem on the surface.  You are welcome to reask it there, but I would prefer not to migrate.